# Laravel Spark 403 - REDIRECT HOST MISMATCH when 3D Secure Payment

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments, laravel-cashier, laravel-spark

I am using Laravel Spark for billing my customers. In case they will pay with 3D Secure cards (I test it with card no. from stripe doc's https://stripe.com/docs/testing#regulatory-cards: 4000 0027 6000 3184) I have the following problem:

The stripe pop-up/modal opens and I click 'Complete Authentication'.

[image]

After that the authentication process starts and the user gets directed to http://127.0.0.1:8000/stripe/payment/pi_xxx?redirect=/home

Here I get the following Laravel error (I do not find other error causes in console or somewhere else):

[image: 403-error]

I've added `stripe/*` in `VerifyCsrfToken` Class already...
Maybe do I need to test this case on my server?

Very weird and I guess thats a sign that I do not have any issues with stripe, with laravel instead. When I remove the query parameter `?redirect=home` I get this screen:

[image]

When I proceed I do not get redirected.. Of course because there is no redirect uri...

Does any one had this issue before?

Comment: Shoot, I am was very glad to read this error, I am experiencing the exact same thing as we speak. Then I scrolled down, no answer! I'll check for a solution as well, will share if I find it. I have a similar error when I do a single charge payment, there is a big fat error and the user gets an email to confirm the payment. Very annoying.

Comment: @helloworld I’ve already build a workaround as well. I will post it here tomorrow. In my opinion it’s a bug in the Spark library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this is a bug in Spark. I've searched for all occurences where Stripe used a redirect. One indication for me that this could really be a bug is:

In `subscription-notice.blade.php` file there ist the link build as follows:

```
{!! __('Please :linkOpen confirm your payment :linkClose to activate your subscription!', ['linkOpen' => '<a href="/'.config('cashier.path').'/payment/'.auth()->user()->subscription()->latestPayment()->id.'?redirect='.url('/home').'">', 'linkClose' => '</a>']) !!}
```

The part `'?redirect='.url('/home').'` creates a full valid URL with host address.
Not only a relative path! These relative paths runs into the 403 Error in my case.
Like in the `RegisterController`:

```
/**
 * Handle a registration request for the application.
 *
 * @param  \Laravel\Spark\Contracts\Http\Requests\Auth\RegisterRequest  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function register(RegisterRequest $request)
{
    list($user, $paymentId) = Spark::interact(
        Register::class, [$request]
    );

    Auth::login($user);

    event(new UserRegistered($user));

    if ($user instanceof MustVerifyEmail && ! $user->hasVerifiedEmail()) {
        $user->sendEmailVerificationNotification();
    }

    return response()->json([
        'redirect' => $paymentId ?
            '/'.config('cashier.path').'/payment/'.$paymentId.'?redirect='.$this->redirectPath()
            : $this->redirectPath(),
    ]);
}
```

`$this->redirectPath()` returns a relative path. I've changed this part into:

```
return response()->json([
        'redirect' => $paymentId ?
            '/'.config('cashier.path').'/payment/'.$paymentId.'?redirect='.config('app.url').$this->redirectPath()
            : $this->redirectPath(),
    ]);
```

In this case I took the host address from my config and put it in front of the relative path.

Just for better understanding, the returned URL above is used here (`register-stripe.js`):

```
    /*
     * After obtaining the Stripe token, send the registration to Spark.
     */
    sendRegistration(paymentMethod) {
        this.registerForm.stripe_payment_method = paymentMethod;

        Spark.post('/register', this.registerForm)
            .then(response => {
                window.location = response.redirect;
            });
    }
```

There are some more cases where I needed to override some JavaScript or PHP sources...

- register process (showed here)
- update process of payment information
- create subscription with existing account

I hope I could help others with that! If necessary I could also post the exact places where I've changed the redirect URL in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a (dirty?) workaround:

In my StripWebHookController there is some code that makes a notification for the user:

```
if ($billable) {
        $model = config('cashier.model');
        $notifiable = $billable instanceof $model ? $billable : $billable->owner;
        if (in_array(Notifiable::class, class_uses_recursive($notifiable))) {
            $payment = new Payment(StripePaymentIntent::retrieve(
                $payload['data']['object']['payment_intent'],
                $billable->stripeOptions()
            ));
            $notifiable->notify(new $notification($payment));
        }
    }
```

Now, this is a notification that apparently makes the StripePaymentIntent notification that is created in the PaymentController of Cashier (located /var/www/html/site/vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Http/Controllers)

There is a VerifyRedirectUrl middleware that is causing the problem right. So when you comment it out, the 403 disappears:

```
public function __construct()
{
    //$this->middleware(VerifyRedirectUrl::class);
}
```

However, the "go back" button after accepting the payment is not working so I'll check that out. But for now, this 403 is at least gone. If I can't another solution, I'll go with this.

Comment: The back button was still not working, as a dirty workaround I changed the blade file that contains that go back button. Located here: /var/www/html/site/vendor/laravel/cashier/resources/views# more payment.blade.php and added this
             <button type="button" class="inline-block w-full px-4 py-3 bg-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-300 text-center text-gray-700 rounded-lg" onclick="window.location='{{ URL::route('credits.show') }}'">Back home</button>